# Get list item data to update the parent activity data

Tags: android, android-fragments

[This is what I have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHT9V.png)

I have `listView` inside three `tab` fragments which are inside a `mainActivity`. I want to have a view at the bottom of main activity which will not effected by fragment transitions, but the data inside of it must be update with the list item's data change.

I got really confused about how this communication would work. I am sorry if this is an obvious problem. I would be appreciate for any help through sarcasm or any way.

Comment: use custom Listener Interface or otto Bus

Comment: When your tab changes just update your list array with new data and use notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

To have your fragments communicate with the main activity is fairly simple. All you need to do is have your MainActivity implement an interface, and call its methods from any of your Fragments, to notify the main activity of some change.

This would be your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements ArticleActionListener{

    public void onArticleAddedToBasket(Article article) {
        // Increment the value on the bottom view's total TextView,
        // with the price of the article added to basket
    }

    public void onArticleRemovedFromBasket(Article article) {
        // Decrement the value on the bottom view's total TextView,
        // with the price of the article removed from basket
    }
}
```

This would be your interface:

```
public interface ArticleActionListener {
    public void onArticleAddedToBasket(Article article);
    public void onArticleRemovedFromBasket(Article article);
}
```

And this would be your fragment:

```
public class ArticlesListFragment extends ListFragment {
    ArticleActionListener articleCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            articleCallback = (ArticleActionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement ArticleActionListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the methods of ArticleActionListener interface, from anywhere within your Fragments, and they'll be called in your MainActivity.

Let me know if it works for you :D